# BCP Ultility: How to get number of record imported

Tags: sql-server, bcp

In bcp utility, When import/export, command line will show us number of rows that is copied.
I try to get that number for using at another processing but i can't.
The Command line is:

```
bcp AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Department out D:\Department_Test.txt -S SERVER_NAME -T -c
```

The result:

```
Starting Copy...
16 rows copied. 
....
```

Please help me to get the copied rows number.

I try to use FINDSTR in the command line to find rows copied, it can be solved that problem, but i want to find a better solution.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like someone tried to get number too http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic681028-338-1.aspx

Comment: That solution is using for SQL Server. I have to use command line to execute. How can i do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's a hack.

```
DECLARE @output TABLE (id INT IDENTITY, command NVARCHAR(256))

Declare @sql varchar(8000)='bcp AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Department out D:\Department_Test.txt -S SERVER_NAME -T -c'

INSERT INTO @output
exec master..xp_cmdshell  @sql

SELECT cast(Replace(command,' rows copied.','') as int) FROM @output where command like '% rows copied.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking this:

```
bcp AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Department out D:\Department_Test.txt -S SERVER_NAME -T -c
```

You are extracing the whole of the table, therefore you might try

```
bcp "SELECT count(*) FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Department" queryout D:\Department_Rows.txt -S SERVER_NAME -T -c
```

This would output the number of records in the table to a separate txt file.

Or alternatively - which might be better - you can use `BCPROWCOUNT`

> (Returns the number of rows affected by the current (or last) BCP operation.)

You can read about that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130996.aspx)